# Replacing var with type name in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, var

I have the following code:

```
List<string> myCars = new List<string>()
    { "Mercury Cougar", "Dodge Dart", "Ford Taurus SHO",
      "Dodge Charger", "Chevrolet Blazer", "Dodge Neon" };

    var dodges = from someCars in myCars
                 where someCars.Contains("Dodge")
                 orderby someCars descending
                 select someCars;

Console.WriteLine(dodges.GetType()); //System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.String]
```

`dodges.GetType()` returns the fully qualified name in CIL syntax.

If I translate it to C# and use it to replace `var`, it doesn't compile:

> The type or namespace name 'OrderedEnumerable<,>' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System.Linq' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<string, string> dodges = from someCars in myCars
                         where someCars.Contains("Dodge")
                         orderby someCars descending
                         select someCars;
```

This is because the `OrderedEnumerable<string, string>` is not available, only `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<string>` is available.

Why is `OrderedEnumerable<string, string>` not available?

Comment: It's `IOrderedEnumerable<string>`, not `OrderedEnumerable<string, string>`.

Comment: "it doesn't compile" : always include the error message in your question.

Comment: May be because it is `internal` type

Comment: I bet you're looking for [`IOrderedEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852(v=vs.110).aspx) too. The `OrderedEnumerable<TElement, TKey>` is declared `internal` and implements `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` as shown [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2d89a8f513559ba0).

Comment: You could also just go back to using `var`, and then hover your mouse over the name and it'll show you the type.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed you can check yourself. dodges.GetType() returns OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.String] which is OrderedEnumerable<System.String,System.String> in C#.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave you can check yourself. Make it `<string>` and it will compile.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave, As others have noted, [`OrderedEnumerable<TElement, TKey>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2d89a8f513559ba0) is an _internal_ class that inherits from the internal _abstract_ class [`OrderedEnumerable<TElement>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ffb8de6aefac77cc), which implements the `IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>` interface.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not trying to make it compile with some other type. I want to know why the type which it truly is, which is System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.String], is not available to me.

Comment: *Why is OrderedEnumerable<string, string> not available* Because it is an "internal" impementation of the interface. There is no reason why it should be available or documented. With LINQ you should program against interfaces (`IEnumerable<>`, `IOrderedEnumerable<>`, `IQueryable`, `IQueryable<>`)

Comment: If you look around, none of the concrete implementations of LINQ classes that implement `IEnumerable<>` and other similar interfaces are public.

Comment: Add a ‘.ToList()‘ to your query, then you can use ‘List<string>‘. Right now you are storing the query, not the result!

Comment: @HansKesting That would defeat the point of the question.

Comment: @AustinWBryan if I do that it just shows me the C# version of System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.String] which I knew anyway.

Comment: @HansKesting if I add .ToList() to my result then the GetType() method would no longer return System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.String] which is precisely what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is `OrderedEnumerable<string, string>` not available

Because it is an "internal" impementation of the interface. There is no reason why it should be available or documented. With LINQ you should program against interfaces (`IEnumerable<>`, `IOrderedEnumerable<>`, `IQueryable<>`...)

If you take a look, all the LINQ methods return an internal class that derives from one of those interfaces, and often they can return instances of multiple different classes, depending on the input. For example the [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs) can return a `new SelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>` or a `SelectIListIterator<TSource, TResult>` or a `new SelectIPartitionIterator<TSource, TResult>` or various other classes, depending on the type of the `IEnumerable<>` input.